# How can I change a variable using self.<variable> in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to iOS and I'm using a third-party package called KeyboardKit to create a custom keyboard. However, I've noticed that it's slightly different from the tutorials I've read. In my code, I have to use 'self.' or else Xcode shows a warning. So, the code I have written is as follows. The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to change the value of the variable using 'self.'. Could you please guide me on how to accomplish that?

```
import UIKit
import KeyboardKit
import SwiftUI

class KeyboardViewController: KeyboardInputViewController {
    
    @State var text = "init" //the variable
        
    override func viewWillSetupKeyboard() {
        super.viewWillSetupKeyboard()
        
        setup { controller in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {

                    
                Button(self.text){
                    self.text = "changed" //change the variable
                }
                
                Text(self.text) //binding the variable
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `State` only works inside SwiftUI Views. SwiftUI is very strict, you should explore the documentation further especially if it notes how to interface between SwiftUi and UIKit. It is an unorthodox setup.

Comment: Thank you. I have now included the variable in the class without using @State. However, I am unsure how to make the Text display the value dynamically.

Comment: That is why you need to look at the documentation. I dont use `KeyboardKit` so I cant tell you exactly how to do it without a working project but from what I can tell by glancing at the git is that you will need an `ObservableObject` and `@ObservedObject` and `@Published`.

Comment: Thank you. I will review the document once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First something to note...

SwitUI is a declarative framework and UIKit is an imperative framework.

This means with UIKit we manually tell it when to display new data and SwiftUI figures out on its own via a very strict protocols when to show new data.

When interfacing between them you have to take both frameworks into consideration and have to play by the rules with both.

SwiftUI uses `DynamicProperty` to identify when to redraw and these `DynamicProperty` are in the form of "property wrappers".

Most the SwiftUI wrappers have to be located in a SwiftUI `View` in iOS 13-16 there were 2 exceptions (iOS 17 has more) with the most relevant being `@Published` that is a `Combine` property wrapper so you can use it as a publisher and it also triggers a SwiftUI reload.

Here is a basic setup, I havent tested the code so there might be typos.

```
import UIKit
import KeyboardKit
import SwiftUI

class KeyboardViewController: KeyboardInputViewController {
    
    let sharedSource: SharedSource = .init() //Shared source of truth that works with UIKit and SwiftUI
        
    override func viewWillSetupKeyboard() {
        super.viewWillSetupKeyboard()
        
        setup { controller in
            SubView(sharedSource: sharedSource) // You can use property wrappers inside a `View`.
        }
    }
}

//Shared Source
class SharedSourve: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = "init" // Can subscribe to it with UIKit via Combine's `sink` or make changes with any of the available methods.

}

struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sharedSource: SharedSource //Has the ability to tell SwiftUI to redraw.
    //You can also use `@State` here like you had in your original code if you dont need a shared source.
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {                        
                Button(sharedSource.text){
                    sharedSource.text = "changed" //change the variable
                }
                
                Text(sharedSource.text) 
                    
            }

    }

}
```